# how to replace quotes to &quot in sql FOR XML PATH('')

Tags: sql, sql-server

i need to replace quotes in varchar field to `&quot;`

```
SELECT REPLACE('"test"','"','&quot;') FOR XML PATH('')
```

get result:

```
&amp;quot;test&amp;quot;
```

but i need:

```
&quot;test&quot;
```

other sample

```
-- have some table

DECLARE @testtable TABLE (adres varchar(MAX))    
INSERT INTO @testtable VALUES ('somewhere in "place"')

-- need to get xml without quotes, use replace

SELECT REPLACE(Adres,'"','&quot;')   
FROM @testtable FOR XML PATH ('Object')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following
 `SELECT REPLACE('"test"','"','&quot;')`

Comment: no, need to use with FOR XML, part of big query returns xml

Comment: different sample DECLARE @s VARCHAR(max) = '&quot;test&quot;'
SELECT @s FOR XML PATH('')

Comment: @user2685921, please clarify you question with a more representative example of what you are trying to achieve. For example, if the actual value is sourced from a table column, provide a `SELECT` query example with a `FROM` clause instead of a literal.

Comment: I gave examples, this adds the amp

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(
              (SELECT CAST((SELECT @a AS [tag] FOR XML PATH('')) AS varchar(MAX)))
                       ,'''','&apos;'),'"','&quot;')
```